# Generate h:panelGrid from Java list

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How I can generate h:panelGrid from Java list?

```
<h:panelGrid id="entrance_list" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

                        <p:outputLabel for="delay" value="Delay" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="delay" value="#{selectOneMenuView.console}" style="width:125px">
                            ........
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel for="sensor" value="Sensor" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="sensor" value="#{selectOneMenuView.console}" style="width:125px">
                            ...........
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </h:panelGrid>
```

How I can implement this?

Comment: I've done somthing like that do you ant an example ?!?

Comment: Yes, please. Paste here fully working example.

Comment: @PeterPenzov you didn't tag me in your comment you were lucky i've look to your comment.(please go to your comment and add a user tag to notify the proper user)